# Anyone else having trouble getting Notepad++ to update?

Tags: notepad++

I keep getting alerts that a new update package is available for Notepad++, but when I click "Yes", it jumps really quickly to 100% and never downloads anything.

Anyone else?

**Update**

I currently have v5.3.1.0 installed.

**Update 2**

Okay, just downloaded a new executable from sourceforge and installed. That did the trick. Hopefully, it was just a bug in the updater program for 5.3.1.0.

Comment: no, i just get a curl error lol

Comment: I also experienced this, I just went to the web site and downloaded the latest version and installed that manually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure what version you are running, but I just updated to v5.6.6, and in the release notes under v5.6.3, it mentions the fixing of an 'Auto-Updater' bug.

Maybe just download the entire executable again to get past the broken version.

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

What version are you using?  I didn't think Notepad++ had an auto-updater built in, at least I can't see anything that would lead me to believe it did in v4.1.2.

Comment: i'm using 5.6.2 and it has one, under the '?' menu.

Comment: Wow.. guess I'm way behind on my updates.  Looks like that will be a useful feature for me :)

Comment: @JT.WK, using v5.3.1.0.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem...
Just uninstall, scoop the latest installer from [the website](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/uk/download.php), then re-install.