# buggy notepad++ plugin manager

Tags: notepad++

I seem to have this problem that when I open notepad++ it shows the updates available and when I select them to update a dialog box appears saying that updates failed.

I am running windows 7 with notepad++ latest version. Does anyone have a solution to this problem.

Comment: are you sure your network is ok?

Answer (score 0):

For me, Notepad++ is updating fine here.  As @onemach says check your network settings, also perhaps the Notepad++ update servers were offline when it was downloading the update(s).  Alternatively, download the latest installer from the [Notepad++ website](http://www.notepad-plus-plus.org/). It has to be said there have been updater problems in the past;

- [Superuser - Anyone else having trouble getting Notepad++ to update? [closed]](https://superuser.com/questions/104422/anyone-else-having-trouble-getting-notepad-to-update)
- [Notepad++ Forum - Auto updates still don't work](http://sourceforge.net/p/notepad-plus/discussion/331753/thread/b82a5ccc)
- [The Electric ToolBox - Notepad++ fails to updateNotepad++ fails to update](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/notepad-plus-fails-update/)